# не получается создать бд в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

ОШИБКА: исходная база "template1" занята другими пользователями
DETAIL: Эта база данных используется ещё в 1 сеансе.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема простая и причина ошибки сразу указана в тексте ошибки:

> Эта база данных используется ещё в 1 сеансе.

Посмотреть какие это сессии можно запросом:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'template1';
```

Принудительно их завершить запросом:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'template1';
```

После завершения всех сессий к этой базе `create database` успешно выполнится.

---

Непонятна здесь может деталь, при чём тут какой-то `template1` когда вы командуете, допустим,

```
create database newdb;
```

Где тут `template1` и как для создания новой пустой БД мешают сессии в `template1`?

Фокус здесь в том, что вообще-то `create database` не умеет создавать новые базы с нуля из ничего. Это умеет только `initdb` при инициализации всего экземпляра `postgresql`. А `create database` умеет только создавать копию базы указанную параметром `template` со значением по-умолчанию как раз `template1`. При этом, чтобы не получить несогласованное состояние файлов базы из-за параллельного изменения этой базы кем-то ещё `create database` требует, чтобы никто к этой `template` базе не был подключен вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Обобщаю:

1. Запустить следующий скрипт, заменив [datebase] на имя базы данных

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'database';
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'database' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

2. Перезагрузить pgAdmin и удалить вручную (правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать delete/drop)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убить процесс pgAdmin(просто закрыть не достаточно), он мешает что либо создавать или удалять. Потом уже снова включать.